# Compare XML structures

Tags: xml, diff

I have 2 XML files. Their content is very different. But they differ not so much in the structure.

Let's say the first XML implements a standard in version 1.0 and the second XML file implements the version 1.1 of the same standard.

How can I get the differences in the structure of the 2 files?

Answer (score -1):

Use an XML editor:

[image: XML Diff]

**References**

- [Are there any free Xml Diff/Merge tools available? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871076/are-there-any-free-xml-diff-merge-tools-available)
- [The XML Diff and Patch GUI Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx)
- [XML editors](http://www.xml-dev.com/)
- [Structural Code Comparison for XML: Usage and Limitations](http://blog.devart.com/xml-structure-comparison-explained.html)